# Constant part of string

Tags: python, nlp, analytics

I've got a problem and don't know how to solve it.

E.x. I have a dynamically expanding file which contains lines splited by '\n'

Each line - a message (string) which is built by some pattern and value part which is specific only for this line.

E.x.:

```
line 1: The temperature is 10 above zero
line 2: The temperature is 16 above zero
line 3: The temperature is 5 degree zero
```

So, as you see, the constant part (pattern) is

```
The temperature is zero
```

**Value** part:

```
For line 1 will be: 10 above
For line 2 will be: 16 above
For line 3 will be: 5 degree
```

Of course it's very simple example.
In fact there're too many lines and about ~50 pattern in one file.
The value part may be anything - it can be number, word, punctuation, etc!

And my question is - how can I find all possible patterns from data?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a log message clustering problem.

Trivial solution: replace all numbers with the string `NUMBER` using a regex. You might need to exclude dates or IP addresses or something. That might be enough to give you a list of all patterns in your logs.

Alternately, you might be able to count the number of words (whitespace-delimited fields) in each message and group the messages that way. For example, maybe all messages with 7 words are in the same format. If two different messages have the same format you can also match on the first word or something.

If neither of the above work then things get much more complicated; clustering arbitrary log messages is a research problem. If you search for "event log clustering" on Google Scholar you should see a lot of approaches you can learn from.

Answer (score 0):

If the no of words in a line is fixed, like in your eg str, then you can use `str.split()`

```
str='''
The temperature is 10 above zero
The temperature is 16 above zero
The temperature is 5 degree zero
'''

for line in str.split('\n'):
   if len(line.split()) >= 5:
       a,b = line.split()[3], line.split()[4]
       print(a,b)
```

Output:

```
10 above
16 above
5 degree
```

Comment: No, not fixed. This is just example

Comment: Ok, then can you paste the actual input string? :)

Answer (score 0):

First, we would read the file line by line and add all sentences to a List.

In the example below, I am adding few lines to a list.

## This list has all sentences..

lstSentences = ['The temperature is 10 above zero', 'The temperature is 16 above zero', 'The temperature is 5 degree above zero','Weather is ten degree below normal', 'Weather is five degree below normal' , 'Weather is two degree below normal']

## Create a list to store all patterns

lstPatterns=[]

## Initialize

intJ = len(lstSentences)-1

## Compare  one sentence against the one that follows it. If there are more than 2 matching words between two setences, perhaps this is a pattern.

```
for inti, sentence in enumerate(lstSentences):    
    if intJ!=inti:
        lstMatch = [ matching for matching in sentence.split() if matching in 
lstSentences[inti+1].split()]
        if len(lstMatch)>2:  #We need min 2 words matching between sentences
            if not ' '.join(lstMatch) in lstPatterns: #if not in list, add
                lstPatterns.append(' '.join(lstMatch))
            
        lstMatch=[]
    
print(lstPatterns)
```

I am assuming patterns come one after the other (i.e., 10 rows with one pattern and then, 10 rows with another pattern). If not, the above code needs to change